# How to Make Your ListView have Capability of Showing All FileTypes

Tags: android, listview

There are Times Like in the Messenger App, You ListView Changes Depending on Type of your Field,Some times Pure text, Some times Image,Video,Music, i know i can add 1 for each type , and hide / release them upon need, but its the hard and unProfessional way, Is there any Better Way, Like Creating View's Upon Need and Hiding old One,Upon Order Guys? How does Your Experience Help? Thanks alot<3

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom adapter, and in the `getView` method, just inflate different layouts depending on the file type, like this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) cx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
if([is one type]){
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_first_type, parent, false);
}
else{
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_second_type, parent, false);
}
```

If you don't know how to use custom adapters, I'd suggest [this tutorial](http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92).

Comment: i Have a custom Cursor adapter, the thing you say is not possible with view holder